# Connection failed. FlowSocketConnector: Failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10060:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

> 01:09:44.788 Connection failed. FlowSocketConnector: Failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I created `t2.micro` free instance on AWS, and I noticed it volume storage isn't enough for me. so I modified the volume storage, increased storage size to **15G**.

And after rebooting instance, I can't access the instance via ssh, I am getting above error.

Please let me know how can I fix this error, Thank you in advance!